# ASP.NET Core BadImageFormatException for libuv.dll

Tags: iis, asp.net-core

We recently migrated an ASP.NET Core project from the old project.json format to the new .csproj one.

Everything runs fine on our development machines. But once the application is deployed on the server, IIS fails to launch the application with a 502.5 (Process Failure) exception. The Windows event log mentions a BadImageFormatException for libuv.dll.

Has anyone encountered this? What could be the source of the problem?

Comment: @Can you update you question and show the content of .csproj file?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, when an ASP.NET Core project is migrated to the csproj format, there are certain conditions under which the resulting csproj will not receive an explicit `<PlatformTarget>`.

And Visual Studio doesn't seem to behave identically when doing a usual build vs. publishing.

In both bases, it will build an PE32 executable with the 32BITREQ flag (32-bits only). But when publishing, it will deploy 64-bit libraries alongside, leading to the aforementioned BadImageFormatException, while it doesn't do that in a non-publish build.

Solution: In the project property page, reselect the platform in the dropdown list. Event if it doesn't have any visual effect, an explicit `<PlatformTarget>` will be added to the csproj on save and this solved my problem.